# Django choice field validation in admin

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model that has a choice field with choices loaded in the runtime.

```py
from some_utils import get_currency_options

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True, blank=True, default="USD", choices=[])

    def clean(self):
    # getting the currency options at execution time, options may vary at different times
    currency_code_options = get_currency_options()

    if self.currency and self.currency not in currency_code_options:
        raise ValidationError({"currency": f"Invalid currency code {self.fb_check_currency}."})

    super(Product, self).clean()
```

Please ignore the bad design here, it was defined like this since we need to integrate with a legacy system.

In the Django admin, I have a form like this

```py
from some_utils import get_currency_options

class ProductAdminForm(ModelForm):
    currency_choices = get_currency_options()

    @staticmethod
    def _values_list_to_options(values_list):
        return [(val, val) for val in values_list]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["currency"] = ChoiceField(choices=self._values_list_to_options(self.currency_choices))

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProductAdminForm
```

Now the problem is, when I go to Django admin and want to update the currency option, it fails to save with an error saying currency is not a valid option. I understand this is due to the choice list being empty, I tried to override the `clean` and `clean_all` method but it didn't work.

Which method does the admin update operation trigger? Is there a way I can use the `get_currency_options` method to load currency options to the validator so if my selection matches one of the value, it passes the validator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same error. In your case, you need overview the `clean_field` method in your model class. For example:

```
from some_utils import get_currency_options

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True, blank=True, default="USD", choices=[])

    def clean_fields(self, exclude=None):
        exclude = ['currency']
        super().clean_fiedls(exclude=exclude)

    def clean(self):
        self.validate_currency()
        super().clean()

    def validate_currency(self):
        # getting the currency options at execution time, options may vary at different times
        currency_code_options = get_currency_options()

        if self.currency and self.currency not in currency_code_options:
            raise ValidationError({"currency": f"Invalid currency code {self.fb_check_currency}."})
```

Comment: So when a model is saved through admin, it calls `clean`, and then inside `clean` it actually calls `clean_fields` to validate each field, am I understanding this right?

Comment: Actually no :)
Methods `clean_fields` and `clean` will be called in `full_clean` method and they are not related to each other. In this case, I use `clean` to do some validating for currency field because in clean_fields they was added to exclude list, and actually haven`t any validation.